# if statement using "sed" to set variable not working

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed

I'm trying to get an if statement to read the top line of a text file (tmp.txt) which has 0 on the last line. the "then" commands basically go into a directory and run a series of commands for DNA sequence analysis before coming back up, removing the top line of tmp.txt and moving onto the next directory listed in tmp.txt. once it gets to the end of all the listed directories the final line will just be a "0" or perhaps "file-end". The issue is, it's just not working and I can't figure out why. I've swapped out the "then" and "else" commands to make testing a bit easier.

```
#!bin/bash/sh
value=`(sed -n 1p tmp.txt)` 
if ($value -eq 0) 
then
echo "I wish i could eat cheese again" 
else
echo "theres still more barcodes left" 
fi
```

Comment: Give [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net) a try. It autodetects several common issues and can be integrated into your editor.

Answer (score 2):

Parenthesis like that in `bash` create subshells to run the enclosed commands in.  You don't need them at all for the `sed` command, and they aren't what you're looking for to test values in the `if` command.  Rather than using backticks, the preferred way of running a command and storing its value now adays is `$(...)` syntax.

For arithmetic tests you can use double parens `((...))`, or you can use the `[` synonym for `test` or `bash` has an extended version `[[...]]`.  With `[` especially, a space after the bracket is essential, since you are trying to run the command `[` in that case.

Putting those things together we can update your snippet like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(sed -n 1p tmp.txt)
if [[ $value -eq 0 ]] 
then
    echo "I wish i could eat cheese again" 
else
    echo "theres still more barcodes left" 
fi
```

(Also, I fixed the shebang line to point to `/bin/bash`, instead of an executable apparently named `/bin/bash/sh` which likely doesn't exist)

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!